# jquery version change error

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is happening because of jquery version change. Previous version was “jquery1.2.3” and the newer version is “jquery1.7.2”.

Example Code:

```
var x = $(“.a”).click(function(){});
console.log(x);
```

Whenever I run the code with different version, I am getting the value with different format.
Is there any way to get data format like jquery1.2.3 by using only jquery1.7.2?

*Tried to use jquery-migrate but did not get any success.
*Can’t keep both version(As per Client requirement)

Comment: What do you expect to get when assigning event?

Comment: Use `""` instead of `“”`

Comment: What is the use of getting an event into a variable?

Comment: In 1.2.3 the output is `Object { 0=div.a,  length=1,  prevObject={...},  more...}` while in 1.7.2 the output is `Object[div.a]`, I haven't tracked down why this is the case, they seem to have comparable properties, what are you getting out of the old format that you can't get form the new one?

Comment: Editing the code little bit, I think now you can understand the problem. 
If you run this code in 1.2.3 it is return a function but for 1.7.2 it is returned a object.

var a = $("p").click(function(){});
    var ev = a.data("events")['click'];
    $(".a").click(function(){
      for (i in ev)
      console.log(ev[i])  
    });

Answer (score 0):

`var x = $(".a").click(function(){});`
 x means the return value of `click()`, it is not `$(".a")`

```
var x = $(".a");
x.click(function(){

});
console.log(x);
```